# How could the length property for String be overriden

Tags: javascript, string, object, constructor

Could someone guide me how to set my own length for a `String`, as in `"string".length` or `String("string").length`.

Afaik, `String` is a descendant from `Object`, and the length assignment probably takes place in the `prototype.constructor`, as well as in the `prototype.__defineSetter__;`

*Edit:*
The motivation is to learn how far  javascript in current Browsers can pushed in order to implement one's own language in it. Operator overloading is my second great concern, which seems is intentionally blocked (i.e. no arguments passed to the operator function).

Some motivation comes from:

http://code.google.com/p/traceur-compiler/

---

UPDATE:
Addition to new Objects can be locked with:
Object.preventExtensions(String.prototype);

Object.seal(obj)...disallows configurability

Object.freeze(obj)...additionally disallows writing

see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806191(v=vs.94).aspx#Y240

I guess there may be some way do undo this locking states....

Redefinition could be done like this:

```
 Object.defineProperty(String, "length", {
        value: 101,
        writable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
```

However will throw "redefine_disallowed" in Chrome V8.

The JS-engine code that throws the error can be found here under DefineOwnProperty:

http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/src/v8natives.js?r=8073

Comment: Did you try actually changing the string's length? :P. On a more serious tone, why on earth would you want that?!

Comment: Yeah I don't think that is something you really want to do

Comment: Yes I did tinker around with prototypes, __defineSetter__ and defineProperties.

I would like to know how far I can push the native "Object" in current Browsers. This allows much easier implementation of a programming language on top on javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not quite possible. Theoretically, this would do the job:

```
Object.defineProperties(String.prototype, {
    length: {
        get: function(){ return 1; }
    }
});
```

But on Chrome it fails with the error `redefine_disallowed`.

I honestly think there is a better solution for your scenario.

Comment: Good answer; I hit the same deadend.

Indeed, at least the method is there:
http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/